# Default hashCode for null object

Tags: java, hashcode

In Java, `Objects.hash(null)` return 0

but

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = null;
Objects.hash(map)
```

will return 31

Comment: null is not an object with a `.hashCode()` method. (And on a programming note: what would hashing `null` even achieve?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to how varargs are interpretted. Under the hood, varargs parameters are implemented by creating an array.

In the `Objects.hash(null)` case, you are passing obviously literally passing null. There is no array. When you do `Objects.hash(map)`, this is converted to an array of length 1, with null as the first and only element.

Because of the way that hash code is calculated, null and an array with 1 null element get different hash codes.